# How to separately count number of files, directories, symbolic links and hard links within a single find run?

Tags: find, symbolic-link, migration, hardlink

To check a successfull migration I'm using `find` to count the number of files, directories, symbolic links and files with more than one hard link. As the directories to check contain a huge number of files, each `find` run takes several hours. Thus I search for a way to separately count number of files, directories, symbolic links and files with more than one hard link within a single `find` run.

Here's what I currently do

```
num_files=$(find $directory -type f | wc -l)
num_directories=$(find $directory -type d | wc -l)
num_symlinks=$(find $directory -type l | wc -l)
num_hardlinks=$(find $directory -type f -links +1 | wc -l)
```

How can I get those four counters within one `find` run?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best approach to comparing two directories. Are you sure this is what you should be asking?

Comment: The best way to compare two directories is probably a dry run of `rsync`. But I need to proof that rsync copied all files, directories, symbolic links and hard links and I don't know a better way than doing it with `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do it. It requires GNU `find`; on OS X, install e.g. `findutil` using Homebrew.

```
find $directory -type d -printf d -o -type l -printf l -o -type f -links +1 -printf h -o -type f -printf f
```

This will print one character per encountered file system entry:

- `d` if it's a file
- `l` if it's a symbolic link
- `h` if it's a file with hard links
- `f` if it's a file (only if not `h`)

Output looks like this (actual excerpt on my system):

> `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`

Redirect output to a file, and then it becomes simple string processing to count later.

Comment: It worked fine on Mac OS X for me, but unfortunately I have to run the command on SunOS 5.10 where find doesn't support printf. Any suggestions how to achieve the same without printf?

Comment: @FlorianFeldhaus You're on an almost decade old Solaris? You should probably add that to your question. Other than to compile and install a better `find`... no idea. FWIW OS X `find` does *not* support `-printf`, you probably installed something better already.

Comment: Yes, I currently have to use it. The tools on it are not that old, but Solaris `find` does not support `printf`. I will try to get a Linux server where I have a recent GNU `find`.

Answer (score 5):

```
find $directory -type d -exec echo dirs \; -o -type l -exec echo symlinks \; -o -type f -links +1 -exec echo hardlinks \; -o -type f -exec echo files \; | sort | uniq -c
```

Produces output like:

```
 326 dirs
2164 files
  40 hardlinks
 164 symlinks
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/623487/how-to-separately-count-number-of-files-directories-symbolic-links-and-hard-li/623491#623491) from [Daniel Beck](https://superuser.com/users/22317/daniel-beck) I developed the following solution which should work for most versions of `find` and also provides the counting magic:

```
output=$(find $directory -type d -exec printf d \; -o -type l -exec printf l \; -o -type f -links +1 -exec printf h \; -o -type f -exec printf f \;)
num_files=$(echo $output | grep -o "f" | wc -l)
num_directories=$(echo $output | grep -o "d" | wc -l)
num_symlinks=$(echo $output | grep -o "l" | wc -l)
num_hardlinks=$(echo $output | grep -o "h" | wc -l)
```